Google Drive API folder/files not refreshing after deleting from Google Drive
I have a html form with input fields to upload files to a Google Drive shared folder via service account (editor permission). It's using Java Google Drive API. After deleting the files/folders in the Google Drive UI as the owner (I no longer see them in the Drive - not even in the Trash), I still see the files/folder in the file listing returned by the Google Drive API.
Is this a permission issue or is deleting as the owner won't affect the service account? Is there a way to refresh the service account data (I don't see such an option in the API doc) or I have to manually delete the files for the service account via API?
